# Не срабатывает await

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

Бек на `Django`, а фронт на чистом `JS/HTML/CSS`. Ничего, кроме `font awesome` не используется.

Для тестов перезапускую полностью сервер и делаю `Ctrl+Shift+R` что бы сбросить кеш статических файлов.

Есть вот такой код метода `init`

```
init() {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async (event) => {
        console.log(`UserOffice init`);
        this.profile = await base.getProfile();
        console.log(`UserOfficeProfile is ${this.profile}`);
        ...
    });
}
```

Код метода `getProfile`

```
async getProfile() {
    const profile = await this.getXHRasync(`${window.location.origin}/api/get_profile/`)[0];
    console.log(`getProfile got ${profile}`)
    return profile;
}
```

И код метода `getXHRasync`

```
getXHRasync(path) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', path, true);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            console.log(`GET XHR 2, path is ${path}, and response ${xhr.responseText}`);
            resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        };
        xhr.send();
    });
}
```

Я не спец в `JS`, просто нужно было провести рефактор. Насколько я понял `await` должен подождать значение и только потом продолжить выполнение кода.

Но на выхлопе получаю.

Вроде везде `async/await` проставил, может, я чего-то не знаю, поправьте

[image: лог консоли]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй в коде getProfile сначала дождаться выполнения async, а потом брать что то по индексу, а то получается, что ты берешь значение по индексу от промиса.

```
async getProfile() {
    const profile = (await this.getXHRasync(`${window.location.origin}/api/get_profile/`))[0];
    console.log(`getProfile got ${profile}`)
    return profile;
}
```

Comment: Сработало, спасибо) Вроде как бы логично, а вроде и нет. Теперь лучше промисы и их синтаксис пойму